# how do i write realistically as if i am being abused?

Tags: description

I can never think of anything other than the fact that being abused  hurts because I can't relate to it .A little help please?

Comment: Strongly related, since it's about writing an abused character: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/58733/23927

Comment: Why do you want to write about abuse if you have no idea what to write about it and can't relate?

Comment: It's sometimes necessary to write about things you don't know and can't experience firsthand. That's when research comes into the picture. Besides books and biographies, in this day and age you can easily find discussion boards covering every topic on abuse you could imagine. Here are some examples: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1d5wss/what_is_the_worst_childhood_memory_that_you_can/ or https://www.psychforums.com/search.php?st&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&keywords=abuse

Answer (score 1):

The true sign of intelligence is imagination, not knowledge. **Imagine**, and if you can't, you can always use people who have been abused as reference material.

If someone ever tells you to write only about what you know, say no. You can write about whatever you want as long as you write it well.

Comment: Maybe so, but this doesn't answer the question of *how* to write it.

Answer (score 0):

**In short, three things: do your research - be specific - ask questions.**

To drill down further in each of them:

***Do your research:***

Read books by specialists, first-hand accounts by people who have experienced abuse and come out of it. Watch things like '[Unorthodox](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9815454/)' and [others](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls041791201/).

***Be specific:***

Note the details of how characters behave, and what their 'tells' are.

If your character is to be convincing, then they will go through a range of emotional states and thought processes. It is up to you whether you show character development or whether you want to provide the reader with an experience which makes them want to shout at the character ... telling them to DO SOMETHING because they have started to care about them and what happens to them.

The realism you hint at wanting in your question will come out of standard writing techniques of descriptive writing and insightful dialogue, among other things.
You will have more freedom by writing in the third person rather than in the first, but as an imaginative exercise it is important to experience things from the point of view of each of the characters you're writing about, as well as from the point of view of the observer (who may or may not be reliable or biased).

***Ask questions:***

In what way is your character being abused? Physically? Verbally? Emotionally?
How do they feel? What do they think - ahead of the abusive interaction, during the abusive interaction, and after the abusive interaction?

How do they express their feelings? Do they rage outwardly, but in private? Do they suppress their emotions? What is their body language? Is there some form of 'body leakage'?

Another question to ask is to what extent either abuser or abused are aware of what they are doing, and if this changes, what triggers the change.

Good luck!